# nginx - which way is better to redirect and why

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect, regular-expressions

I want to redirect from www.mydomain.com to domain.com in nginx. I search the internet and found two ways:

**First way**

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  www.domain.com;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

**Second way**

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  www.domain.com;
            return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Both ways work. But Which one should i use and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second way is better...

```
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name  www.domain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Why**

Let me quote directly from the official Nginx wiki at [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#Taxing_Rewrites):

> By using the built-in variable $request_uri,
>   we can effectively avoid doing any capturing or matching at all,
>   and by using the return directive,
>   we can completely avoid evaluation of regular expression.

My own thoughts...

By default, the regex is costly and will slow down the performance.